# Можно ли после удаления строк из БД получить обратно количество удаленных строк?

Tags: c#, oracle

Я удаляю строки в БД. Можно ли получить обратно количество удаленных строк?

```
public string DeleteOracle()
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

            // Формируем запрос
            OracleCommand OraCmd = new OracleCommand($"delete from ", Connect);

            // Проходим ридером
            using (OracleDataReader OraReader = OraCmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (!OraReader.HasRows) return result;
                while (OraReader.Read())
                {
                    result = "Запрос ушел";
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OracleCommand OraCmd = new OracleCommand("delete from table_name", Connect);

int count = OraCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
result = count > 0? "something was deleted" : "no records deleted";
return result;
```

[ExecuteNonQuery](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idbcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Странно, ТС принял ответ, но не проголосавал за него. Чем то остался недоволен?